# how to execute a command in CMD from a WPF application?

Tags: windows, cmd

i need help with a small programm, i just want to start a CMD and then run a command like: `dir`

so i did the following:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "dir");
```

the problem is, that `dir` is not executed in the cmd.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/c dir");
```

or

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k dir");
```

to keep the command window open.

Comment: this is cool, but the cmd windows closes after this directly, how to keep it open?